# How to remove a water mark at the bottom right of a png with Imagick

Tags: php, images

Ubuntu 16.04
PHP 7.2

We use Imagick to place a  transparent png image of a vehicle over a jpg background. The watermark from the company we purchase the images from appears at the bottom right of the vehicle image and sometimes appears on our final image. How do we ignore the bottom right of the transparent vehicle PNG when we create the final image?

Or

How can I trim 25px from the top and 25 px from the bottom of the original vehicle png?

[image]

Comment: If you're buying the images you should be able to negotiate for pictures without a watermark. Otherwise you may find that removing their mark is breaking the terms of your contract.

Comment: I am well within my rights to do as I please with these images. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Pleased to hear it. Nevertheless it may be worth seeing if you can avoid the pain of removing a watermark by asking for images that don't have one in the first place.

Comment: What pain are you referring to? It's a line of code, nothing more :)

Comment: GANs can do it automatically these days, not sure if some photo editing tool has some kind of GAN plugin.